# Using a form to display previous entries and add new ones

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to design a simple wildlife tracking DB, so that when myself or my colleagues spot an animal we can enter its ear tag number via a form. That will either bring us up a list of previous dates/locations that animal was observed, or if it's not in the DB, allow us to enter the new animal and location.

I have two main data tables:
dt_Animal - which stores the ear tag info, species, and other information about that unique animal
dt_Sightings - stores info on when/where animals been seen (linked to dt_Animal in a one-to-many relationship, of course)

What I want is that when you open up the form, you get a box (text or combo) to enter the animal's ear tag ID.

- If the ID *already exists* in the DB, it brings up all the info on that animal and its previous sightings - with the option to fill out any missing info and (of course) to add a new sighting - and it WILL NOT add a new record to dt_Animal - just to dt_Sightings
- If the ID *doesn't exist* in the DB, it creates a new record in dt_Animal and allows you to enter any/all of the other information

Where I'm running into problems is that I don't want duplicate records in dt_Animal - each animal is unique.

So far, I've gotten it so that if the eartagID value you've entered is already present in dt_Animal, instead of just popping up a warning, the form will bring up the associated data in the 'Sightings' subform, so you can see where the animal has been previously as well as add your new sighting.

Any help would be appreciated!  I had been getting some help at another forum until the person helping me was banned for a fracas on another thread...!
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1249087

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't tried it already, I would suggest using a `Form` for Animals that uses standard text boxes, combo boxes, etc., to display/edit the animals' details **and** uses a linked `Subform control` to display/edit their sightings all at once, like this:

[image: SubformExample.png]

The main form is bound to [dt_Animal], so you don't run the risk of creating duplicates in that table if [eartagID] is the Primary Key (which it should be). The "Sightings" *subform* is bound to [dt_Sightings] and *linked* to [dt_Animal] by [eartagID], so

- it only shows the Sightings for the current Animal
- if you add a new Sighting it will automatically link that Sighting to the current Animal (i.e., automatically insert the correct [dt_Sightings].[eartagID]).

### Edit

To make searching/adding animals more "seamless", one approach would be to add a text box `txtAddSearch` and a command button `cmdAddSearch` to the form header with the following code behind the form:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAddSearch_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    If Not IsNull(Me.txtAddSearch.Value) Then
        Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
        rst.FindFirst "eartagID=" & Me.txtAddSearch.Value
        If rst.NoMatch Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNewRec
            Me.eartagID.SetFocus
            Me.eartagID.Text = Me.txtAddSearch.Value
            Me.species.SetFocus
        Else
            Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
        End If
        Set rst = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.cmdAddSearch.Default = True
    Me.txtAddSearch.SetFocus
End Sub
```

When the form first loads you are looking at the first data record, but `txtAddSearch` has the focus:

[image: OnLoad.png]

You type in an EarTagID and hit [Enter]. If the record already exists then you are taken to it...

[image: KillerRabbit.png]

...and if the EarTagID doesn't already exist you are taken to a new record (with that EarTagID already filled in) so you can add the details:

[image: NewRecord.png]

Comment: Thanks Gord - that is how I have it set up; the problem is that if I have the EartagID field set as the Primary Key, it won't allow me to create a duplicate (which is good)...but when this happens though, instead of getting an error box, I want it to bring up the previous info associated to that EartagID.

Comment: Oh, okay, it's navigation issue. Instead of typing the eartagID into the text box, you can click the eartagID text box (to give it the focus) and then choose "Find" on the "Home" tab of the Access ribbon bar (or hit [Ctrl-F], which, like most other apps, is the keyboard shortcut for "Find"). That's how you can locate the (existing) record for that Animal.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I guess what I'm trying to get at is I would like it to be seamless - you won't know if an animal is in the DB or not, so rather than having to search to check - you just enter it in and the DB 'figures out' if it's an existing record or a new record.
I've been trying to get at it by using VB in the BeforeUpdate property, but haven't cracked it yet.

Comment: Thanks so much!  You've cracked it and it seems to be working great.  Just need to make some tweaks!